# War not getting deployed in weblogic on changing camel version

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, weblogic

I have spring project that is using apache camel version `2.13.2` and when i try to update the version to `2.18.1`. My war fails to start and throws the following error -

```
Target state: deploy failed on Server Common
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.backoff.BackOff
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:464)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:441)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.chooseMessageListenerContainerImplementation(JmsConfiguration.java:691)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:681)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint.java:183)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:178)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:71)
at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:103)
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:167)
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3615)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3522)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3308)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3162)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:182)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2953)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2976)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2953)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2920)
at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:275)
at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:353)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:725)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1910)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Is there any specific reason why this is happening or what and where i should look as i am really clueless as to why change in `camel` results in spring's class not being found?

And apart from this, all my routes made in java configuration are not working and throw exceptions like `consumer not found for endpoint` for all the routes that consume message from given endpoint but same seems to work in when writen in xml. Is there any reason for this? I am using camel 2.13.2 and java configuration for routes is done by extending RouteBuilder, also i have other routes that are already written in xml and the xml has been added in `contextConfigLocation`. Is it somehow related to adding xml in contextConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camel-jms:2.18.1` component uses `spring-jms` with version `4.3.4.RELEASE`. You need to upgrade to spring `4.3.4.RELEASE` or migrate `camel-jms` component to `camel-sjms`, which does not use spring. You can find all relevant dependencies in [camel-parent-2.18.1.pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.18.1/camel-parent-2.18.1.pom)

---

If you are using Maven, the best way to keep your dependencies consistent is using BOM:

```
<dependencyManagement> 
  <dependnecies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
      <artifactId>camel-parent</artifactId> 
      <version>2.18.1</version> 
      <type>pom</type> 
      <scope>import</scope> 
    </dependency> 
  </dependnecies> 
</dependencyManagement>
```

and then exclude version for all camel and spring related dependencies, which you are using in application.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId> 
</dependency>
...
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```